# Delete all linked tables in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to delete all tables which are linked in my access database.

This is the query which is returned all the linked tables (odbc and access linked tables) :

`SELECT [MSysObjects].[Name]
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE Left([Name],1) <> "~" AND (MSysObjects.Type = 6 OR MSysObjects.Type = 4)
ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name;`

But now i think i have to do a `for each` with this `DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, Table.name` in order to close all my tables, but i don't know how to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Each iterates through a collection in an un-ordered sequence and by deleting an object within that collection during iteration is the reason you encounter an error.

I would suggest that you iterate through the collection in an ordered sequence in reverse order to delete the TableDef objects using:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Set dbs = CurrentDb
For index = dbs.TableDefs.Count – 1 To 0 Step -1
    Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs(index)
    If Left(tdf.Connect, 5) = "ODBC;" Then
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tdf.Name
    End If
Next index
```

Comment: missing a `Set dbs = CurrentDb`

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim rs as New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSql as string

strSql = [put your sql statement here]

rs.open strSql, CurrentProject.connection
Do while not rs.eof
   Docmd.DeleteObject acTable,rs.Fields(0)
   rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

Comment: i have this error : object variable is undefined on this line "rst.Open sql, CurrentProject.Connection"

Comment: Sorry, I have now added the instantiation on the first line. It was missing the `New` keyword.